# accessing to Sympy out put

Tags: sympy

So far I implemented the following code to find the eigenvalues and of the symbolic matrix. Is there any way to access just the first eigenvalue, since I want to plot it versus epsilon.

```
from sympy import * 
e = Symbol(r'\epsilon') 
A = Matrix([[-1, -1], [1/e, -1/e]]) 
lam = A.eigenvals()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object `lam` is of type

```
type(lam)
```

> `dict`

that is, dictionary, and its elements can be accessed by the methods available for dictionaries. Since the eigenvalues appear as dictionary *keys*, you can extract them using `list(lam.keys())`, which returns a list of the eigenvalues. Now you can use the standard indexing technique to extract the eigenvalue you want.

```
lam_0 = list(lam.keys())[0]
print(lam_0)
```

> `-(\epsilon + 1)/(2*\epsilon) - sqrt(\epsilon**2 - 6*\epsilon + 1)/(2*\epsilon)`